# What is the correct width to add a row to a table containing asp items with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, razor, asp.net-core

Apologies if the title doesn't describe the following problem correctly.

Essentially I have the following in my `cshtml` file:

```
<tbody>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ProgrammeScores.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ProgrammeScores[i].Id" />
                <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.ProgrammeScores[i].FileDate" name="@Model.ProgrammeScores[i].FileDate" class="datepicker form-control" aria-describedby="calendar-addon" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select asp-for="@Model.ProgrammeScores[i].ScoreId" name="@Model.ProgrammeScores[i].ScoreIds" asp-items="@Model.Scores" id="ScoreIds" class="select-picker create-select"></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" asp-for="@Model.ProgrammeScores[i].Comments"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

`@Model.Scores` is a `IList<SelectListItem>`

Then, I have a button which adds a new row to the table with empty values, which I want to be editable and therefore allow me to add a new Score to the Programme inline in the actual table.

The Javascript function that adds a row to the table is as follows (I am aware that I am incorrectly trying to use Razor code here  - This is where I need help)

```
function addScorecard() {
    var rowCount = parseInt($('#numOfScores').val());
    var scoreTable = $('#programme-score-table');
    var row = $([
        '<tr>',
        '<td>',
        '<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ProgrammeScores[' + rowCount + '].Id" />',
        '<input type="text" asp-for="@Model.ProgrammeScores[' + rowCount + '].FileDate" name="@Model.ProgrammeScores[' + rowCount + '].FileDate" class="datepicker form-control" aria-describedby="calendar-addon" />',
        '</td>',
        '<td>',
        '<select asp-for="@Model.ProgrammeScores[' + rowCount + '].ScoreId" name="@Model.ProgrammeScores[' + rowCount + '].ScoreIds" asp-items="@Model.Scores" id="ScoreIds" class="select-picker create-select"></select>',
        '</td> ',
        '<td>',
        '<textarea class="form-control" rows="2" asp-for="@Model.ProgrammeScores[' + rowCount + '].Comments"></textarea>',
        '</td> ',
        '<td>',
        '</td>',
        '</tr>'
    ].join("\n"));

    scoreTable.append(row);
}
```

So, my overall question is - what is the correct way to implement this functionality so that whenever I add a new row to the table, the cells are correctly linked to their fields on the Model, for example the `Select` is correctly mapped to `@Model.ProgrammeScores[i].ScoreId`, and also the `asp-items` which come from `@Model.Scores` are correctly set as the options in the `select` dropdown list.

I have already began attempting to pass `@Model.Scores` from the `cshtml` through to the `js` using `<script> var scores = '@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.Scores))'; </script>` but I was still not able to get `asp-items` working for the dropdown.

Many thanks!

Comment: you just need to replace the Razor code with equivalent HTML - the Razor code just outputs HTML anyway, so you should make your code generate the equivalent HTML, as if it has been created by Razor.

Comment: That may potentially involve writing some model data into JS variables at page load (e.g. serialising the scores to JSON and storing them in a variable so you can then create the right options). Or you might make an AJAX call to the server to fetch the latest values.

Comment: Or alternatively, if you do want to use Razor (due to some complexity perhaps), you could make a partial view which outputs just this snippet of HTML, based on some input value (to tell it exactly what to render), and make an AJAX call to an action method which returns that partial view, and then write the HTML returned by the AJAX (i.e. the output of rendering the partial view) directly into your page. As you see, there are a few different ways you could approach this.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson - I didnt realise that the Razor code just outputs HTML anyway. I believe that if I update my js to build up the HTML as per your suggestion it should do the trick. I'll report back

Comment: Yeah if you View Source your page in your browser after it's been loaded from a Razor view, you'll just see HTML. Browsers don't speak Razor, only C# does. Technically you don't _need_ Razor at all to run an ASP.NET app - you could just make all the HTML manually, as long as it then created a form which would post back data that the server can understand (this is, in fact, exactly what you're about to do). Razor is just there to make the model binding and generation of correct HTML a lot easier.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your suggestions. I modified my `addScorecard()` function to simply build up the necessary HTML and after a bit of trial and error, I got the functionality I was looking for!